# Create Lead using DeveloperForce toolkit for .Net

Tags: leads, .net, force.com-toolkit-for-net

I am wondering how to use toolkit for .net to create new leads, because most examples I can find on the net are created using wsdl. I want to know what do I need to do before defining lead, hot to define it and how to update it on application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are examples of creating records using the [Force.com Toolkit for .NET](https://github.com/developerforce/Force.com-Toolkit-for-NET) in [Nothing But .Net – Implementing CRUD Operations](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2014/11/nothing-but-net-crud-operations.html).

You will want something like:

```
public class Lead {
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Company { get; set; }
}

// ...


// Get the client based on your chosen authentication method
ForceClient client = new ForceClient(instanceUrl, accessToken, apiVersion);

Lead lead = new Lead() { LastName = "Doe", Company = "Acme" };

string newLeadId = await client.CreateAsync("Lead", lead);
```

Comment: I am using auth.UsernamePasswordAsync(_consumerKey, _consumerSecret, _username, _password + _securityToken).Wait(); to authenticate, but it crashes saying it has issue with mscorlib.dll, do you have any suggestons?

Comment: @Vilius I'd suggest raising a new question with sample code the reproduces the issue. Ideally you should be using the `await` keyword rather than `.Wait()`